# Divided road segments from XTools Pro need unique, informative IDs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, editing, road

I can divide segments with my road using XTools Pro, but I want to give a useful identifying number to each segment.

For example: If D100 road has been divided into 20 segments, the segments must be numbered 1,2,3,4,5,....20, based on the kilometer location of segments.

How can I do this?

---

I use ArcGIS 10.2.2. Let me try to explain with an example:

I divided road segment A that is 60 km long with XTools, and each of the resulting segments is 1 km. In total I have 60 subdivided segments. But XTools adds same ID for all subdivided road segments (all 60 subdivided parts of segments A have same ID).

[image]

It is hard to detect the kilometer of subdivided parts of segments. Considering that I have a lot of segments, it is impossible to know the location of any (randomly selected) subdivided segments.

Comment: you are very close to an answerable question. Though you tag javascript, you would need to tell us which software you would use. the programming language alone would not provide this capability. I am surprised that xtools doesn't already do this. did you see an xtp_id after the split? Plese edit your original question with more information.

Comment: Are you able/interested in having a scripted solution that can cycle through them and assign IDs? If so -- are the segments "in order" (e.g. is ObjectID 1 the first, 2 the second, etc.) or not?