# Divide road network into road segments

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have a csv file with Latitude and Longitude information along with other information such as Street name. I am using as an example a map of a city and I have different points in the whole city's road network. What I am trying to do is to divide the whole network into small road segments of different sizes depending on each street, like a segment can be 200 meters up to 1km. The only geographical data I am having is "Latitude, Longitude, Street, City".

I have found a similar question here [using XTools on ArcGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127726/divided-road-segments-from-xtools-pro-need-unique-informative-ids) but I am using QGIS. I want to do the same thing. Divide the road network into segments and get a unique ID for each segment with every observation in that segment and its distance.

I tried to do this task using python but it didn't work well, like calculating the haversine distance.

I am new to QGIS and I am using the latest version, 3.14.16-Pi.

Comment: Change CRS to UTM and use plugin qchainage and intesect roads with points.

Comment: I found that to use the QChainage tool I need a line to do chainage on it. How can I mark lines on a road network ?